# Bug in number of answers display

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278400/logging-application-block) recently came up in the [sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sharepoint&sort=newest&pagesize=50) tag. It looked like this showing the queestion has 2 answers:

[SharePoint tag showing question http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/2answerstaggedpage.png](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/2answerstaggedpage.png)

When clicking through to the question it still says there are 2 answers but **only 1 is displayed**:

[Two answers or one http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/2answersqpage.png](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/2answersqpage.png)

I'm assuming that there were two answers but one was deleted and the previous state has been cached.

This is tolerable on the tagged question page because you can't see the answers. However when the question page shows two different things it doesn't look so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug, David DeAngelo deleted his answer*. Wait for the cache to catch-up with reality.

<sup>* Makes sense. It wasn't really an answer.</sup>

Comment: He also deleted his account...

Comment: How long does the cache take?

Comment: @Alex, dunno. That's a separate question entirely :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the mods deleted his account. All he'd done was spam.

Comment: @mm, I see, that would makes sense.  It isn't easy to get your account deleted in under 35 minutes usually.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I flagged the two questions I saw from David DeAngelo and his little dog too. It was his spam that inspired my answer to the "not appropriate stackexchange sites" question.

Comment: This was actually his second account; his first one was deleted a day or two ago for spamming.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was deleted and the question list page had not updated itself yet.